# QtSDK: Is it too slow for a game? Suggestions otherwise?

Tags: qt, opengl, sfml

I am creating an OpenGL game and I am looking for the best cross platform solution. I have experience with QtSDK using QtCreator and I love the signal/slots paradigm (not a fan of MFC, which eliminates wxWidgets) and I think I could easily port what I've already done over to Qt however I fear that due to Qt being widget based it might be too slow for my game. Currently, I generate a (fairly) large terrain and I handle many entities (2-500+) some of which have many particles (~2-500^~2-500) while needing to handle keyboard and mouse input efficiently (all of which I do currently in OpenGL, without anything higher level with the exception of GLew).

I'm also interested in SFML as it could handle Window creation and Audio / Networking, and seems to be pretty friendly with OpenGL.

My question: Have you made a three-dimensional game using QtSDK? Was it responsive? Any tips would be great before I start porting loads of code over to Qt only to be disappointed.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you're making a game, you should avoid using Qt for creating your OpenGL window. You can use Qt for some stuff (Unicode strings, signaling, etc), but Qt doesn't provide for all of the input, sound process, etc needs that you will have in making a game. It won't make it easy to maintain the strict timing most games need.

If you're looking for a cross-platform basis for game development, you should investigate SFML/SDL/Allegro5. All of these are perfectly suitable for game development.

Answer (score 1):

If you're already doing everything in OpenGL, I don't really see a reason to switch. Signals and slots are slower than the manual way, and require a pre-compile build step, which is a hassle to port over.

Qt won't influence performance (or shouldn't at least) if all QGLWidget options are set properly (refresh and redraw rate). If you're going to use OpenGL to draw Qt GL Widgets (which is also possible), that probably will impact performance.

I believe you are forgetting what [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/) is all about: [API by category](http://wiki.libsdl.org/moin.cgi/APIByCategory)

Answer (score 1):

Although I have only a little experience with QT I recently came across one interesting news: http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/12/15/qt-4-8-0-released/

Now it is possible to create "multithreaded" OpenGL solutions. I think it can improve performance. One thread can be solely responsible for the GUI (widgets) and others for OpenGL (one for rendering, one for resource loading, etc).

All in all I think that for simple or casual games QT is enough. Of course you will not be able to create AAA games in it :)

Answer (score 0):

I've created examples with models, etc in Qt awhile back. Qt isn't too slow, or anything. If you want to create a game, or whatever in Qt, then go ahead. Qt offers a lot to the end user using Qt. So ignore all the other responses. I've never had any problem with speed.